# How to close a specific activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activity A, B, and C, in which C is an activity to call HOME screen as follows

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

First, the activity A will call the activity B by

```
Intent B_intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
B_intent .putExtra("B_Activity", true);
this.startActivity(B_intent );
```

Then, from A, I also can call the C activity (A do it by using a thread). My problem is how can I clear/ delete/or finish the activity B when I call C activity, so that when I call the B again, it must be go to onCreate() function in B_Activity class
I try to use the function

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("B_Activity", false))
 {
   finish();
 }
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 solutions for you:

**1)** First of all you simply implement the functionality onResume() method of B_Activity so that when you return from C_Activity to B_Activity it gets executed.

**2)** I strongly recommend **[Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)** are what you should use for such scenarios.

**3)** If this doesn't solve your problem then the best approach for such use case is to make a ***static factory method*** like this:

```
public static void finishActivity(MainActivity mainActivity){
        if(mainActivity!=null)
            mainActivity.finish();
    }
```

Now call:

```
MainActivity.finishActivity(mainActivity);
```

from anywhere you want to close the running instance of the SecondActivity. You have to pass the instance of MainActivity and you can get it once you start it.

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
B.this.finish(); // it will destroys the activity B
```

Before going to activity C via intent destroy the activity B as follows,

```
B.this.finish();
Intent i = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

now when you call the activity B from activity A/C it will call onCreate() of B activity.

Comment: Sorry. I call the activity C from A not from B. So. I cannot use B.this.finish

Comment: elaborate your flow ? im not getting exactly what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I mean I have three activities: A,B,C. From A, I will call B and C. How can I finish the activity B before I call the activity C

Comment: just add B.this.finish() before calling C thts it

Comment: How to call B.this.finish when I am in the activity A

Comment: you can't destroy B from A ... just add that B.this.finish() at the end of B activity's oncreate() method..